# Adding time to flash movie

Tags: flash, datetime, time

i call a flash script from another flash script with the following code:

my_sample.onLoad = function(succes){
      if(succes){
          sample = this.sample_id
          sample_url = "http://www.zzzzzzzzzzzz.com/sample/sample_"+sample+".swf?page="+page+"&dmn="+dn;
          loadMovie(sample_url, "_root.zzz_load", "GET");
      } else trace ("Error loading data")

i need to change it so that it will call a different movie clip each time the clip is viewed, using the time (so that the movieclip will be a new one every time a user refreshes the page or sees the flash again).

How can i do that? what changes should i do to the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a querystring parameter whose value is almost unique.
I used Date.getTime() for that.
Sample code would be:

```
my_sample.onLoad = function(succes)
{
    if(succes)
    { 
        sample = this.sample_id;
        sample_url = "http://www.zzzzzzzzzzzz.com/sample/sample_"+sample+".swf?page="+page+"&dmn="+dn+"&_dtakj=" + (new Date()).getTime(); 
        loadMovie(sample_url, "_root.zzz_load", "GET"); 
    } 
    else trace ("Error loading data")
};
```